# Continuous Animation Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation

I want to make an image move on the Y axis downwards but then come back in the initial position not by redrawing but also by animation. How can I do this? I have tried 2 ways: creating 2 separate animations in the .java file, and then by creating an xml. In the xml I've tried writing a  command inside another < set> command and didn't work. Also i've tried a  command inside another < translate> command. So ... any ideas may be appreciated!

Comment: Communication is paramount when asking question. Please take care of your spelling and punctuation if you want folks to understand you well.

Comment: Also, if someone answers your question to your standard, accept that answer and/or up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

Android includes some commands in code rather than XML that will move things around.  There's a great guide [here](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-2/) that will help you learn how to implement them.

From there, implement an animation listener to tell when the first animation ends (as seen in the Google documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html)) ain order to start the second animation after the first.